# Calculate free energy for a canonical (NVT) ensemble

Tags: molecular-dynamics, free-energy

**Note: Users wishing to answer this question may write a comment or a message in the chat indicating their desire for the question to be re-opened.**

---

I have an NVT ensemble of water molecules (liquid) and I want to calculate the Free energy (helmholtz or gibbs) whichever is equivalent to the following relation:
$$ \Delta F = -RTlnQ \tag{1}$$
I can't calculate the value of Q in a traditional way i.e.
$$ Q=\frac{[Products]}{[Reactants]}\tag{2} $$
Is there any other way to calculate frame-wise free energy? I have the following values at my disposal currently (can calculate more if given a way):

- N (starting number of molecules - NOT intermediate count of reactants and products)
- V (box dimensions)
- T (frame-wise temperature)
- Total Energy (frame wise)
- Potential Energy (frame wise)
- Pressure (framewise)

I have also looked at FEP (Free energy perturbation) but unsure if that is applicable to an existing trajectory and if yes, then how.

Comment: +1 Welcome to the site! You talk about "products" and "reactants", but then the question appears to describe an equilibrium situation (liquid water at some fixed temperature)? I think it would help get a good answer if you clarify this.

Comment: @ProfM why do you say it's at equilibrium? I am infact trying to take a system through a transition state too and calculate the free energy using the same formula

Comment: When I read the question I understood that you had some liquid water at equilibrium. I think it would help if you clarified that you are interested in looking at the system through a transition state and perhaps explain what the initial and final states are; otherwise others may also misunderstand it like I did.

Comment: I agree, it would help to tell us what it is exactly that you are trying to calculate and how you are doing it, because the question is unclear as it stands.

Comment: @ProfM please help me determine this. So my system starts off as water at 300K and then i run an unbiased simulation of the system with a force field that should help me capture some auto ionization. Since it is unbiased it's hard to say what the initial and final states are but there will be an unionized state, a completely ionized state and a tranition state in the middle

Comment: I am no expert in these simulations, so we should wait for someone to provide a proper answer. But I think that editing your question to add this information that you wrote in the comment (starting at 300K, using a force field, interested in describing auto ionization) would greatly help clarify what you need and therefore lead to a good answer.

Comment: You need to mathematically define a collective variable, so that you can set up biased simulations that explore the particular free energy profile along the collective variable that you are interested in. Unless you are going over the kinetic barriers of interest with the unbiased simulation, the data you have now won't be sufficient for what you want. Also, "frame-wise free energies" don't exist, free energy is a statistical concept of the macrostate, not a particular microstate.

Comment: @Godzilla123 I will have to disagree with you on the part that I "have" to define collective variables because from how i understand, the point of collective variables is to drive a reaction across a larger space than an unbiased simulation would in a shorter time. Also, for the second part, aren't pressure, temperature and volume also macrostate variables ? If I have them, why not free energy?

Comment: @fireball.1 Yes, this is what I said: if you need to bias, then you need to define a CV. And I gathered from your question that you do need a bias, no? Basically, if you have the same Hamiltonian and you want to find the free energies of a particular slice of phase space, you need a CV; if you are switching between Hamiltonians you need to run FEP instead.

Comment: The free energy is related to the partition function, which defines the collective thermodynamic weight of a particular region of phase space. This only makes sense if the region has a non-zero phase space volume. For a single frame, this volume is zero, which means that the entropy is zero (because there is only one microstate which corresponds to the frame you are interested in), so the "free energy" of a single frame is its internal energy - hardly a useful concept at all. What does make sense is finding the free energy profile along a CV, but for that you need statistical averaging.

Comment: @Godzilla123 How are we doing here? Should we put a bounty? Should we vote to close? I know nothing about the topic, but I'd like to help the user get their problem solved, or help our community "clean up" some of the unanswered questions so that we can focus on the other unanswered questions.

Comment: @NikeDattani To me the question is unclear and it sounds like the OP is not sure what they want to do in the first place so it is difficult to answer because of this reason (also, as I said, frame-wise free energies don't really make sense so the premise of the question is flawed). I haven't yet voted to close it but I have no intention of answering it either unless the question is made more clear.

Comment: fireball.1, @Godzilla123 is our [top user in the MD tag](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/tags/molecular-dynamics/topusers) so if they find it too unclear to give any answer, I worry that others will too. If it is left open while in this state, it will be distracting for users like me that are working very hard to clean up the unanswered queue. fireball.1: would you be okay if we *temporarily* close your question while you spend as much time as you need, to sort out the issues that GZ mentioned? If you've discovered by talking to GZ that premise of your Q is flawed, u can self-answer.

Comment: @NikeDattani I appreciate that you asked before you close it. Although, I would prefer it to be open so that discussion can be active. However, if you feel that there is no scope at the moment, it's ok to close it. I am working on a few things and should have some answer soon.

Comment: @fireball.1 Luckily the discussion can continue in the comments when a question is closed :) Also we have a [chat room for molecular dynamics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109805/lammps) where people might be able to help you further, if you send them a link to this question.